# 2002 Pontiac Sunfire

Tags: noise, troubleshooting, pontiac, sunfire

I hope someone can give me some insight on what is going on with my car. 2002 Pontiac Sunfire two door.

Over time I have heard a very very faint ticking sound which never really concerned me car ran perfect otherwise and the sound was so faint. I have had the car for a year 156,000 miles when I bought it.I put roughly 2,250 miles on it and have not changed oil yet. oil is not black, still caramel color. I don't drive but just around town.

I heard this ticking sound noticeably louder the other day. I went to switch lanes while driving I didn't have the zippy power normally due. (5 speed) .

Yesterday on my drive home I could hear the louder tapping noise. But now with a weird flapping noise going on and the car cut out briefly but did not stall. Then it was fine (but still heard the noise tapping) within 5 minutes it did it again, that flapping noise and the car cut out just for a split second. I got it home and looked to see if something was broken that was flapping around under the hood and there was nothing. I went out today and started the engine letting it idle. The tapping ticking noise is coming from the left side of the motor but I discovered it is coming right from the spark plug. The spark plug wire was wiggling around bouncing up and down (the part that covers the spark plug) it acts as if it is loose. I can spin it all around and it kinda feels like the spark plug is moving. I can't get the plug off. I tried pulling and pulling but it wont come off.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

I am a woman and before I take it to a mechanic I would like a little insight on what it could be. I don't want to be told I need a whole new motor if I really don't.

Comment: more than likely the plug is broken and the boot melted around the plug. It's going to have to come out in pieces.

Comment: Can you take and post a cellphone picture as close as you can but still in focus?  That might help us narrow down exactly what happened.